# Facebook like plugin showing error

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook's "Like Box" social plugin, for which one can get the code here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

However, when I populate the field entitled "Facebook Page URL" with the URL for my Facebook page, I get an error message in place of where the "Like Box" preview should show up. The error message is:

"Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

I've entered the URL exactly as it appears in the address bar when one navigates to my Facebook profile in a browser. Does this have something to do with my privacy settings on Facebook??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess I had answered this sort of question before. Please google things & read documentation carefully before posting any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add like box for a profile. Have you ever liked any profile on facebook??