# facebook like action error on page plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello i am new at stackoverflow when it comes to post question, this is my first post on SO. I will try to make it clear but if i failed to do so plz plz suggest me before close it or mark it duplicate. I have not found and question/article related to my problem after enough searching. Please propose any solution or helping material. Please help me even if it seems a crazy question, because i am struck here.

I'm trying to add the facebook like and share using fb page-plugin to a site, and use my facebook page as target URL.
i have added og:meta tags in the head of html document and included the generated code of page-plugin from facebook code generator. Added the correct appID. FB api version(2.10) is same in code and  FB app.

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=**********';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I have searched and read many SO posts and facebook docs for developers, search about my problem with many search keywords but unable to find some good guidance posts. i have tried 
[facebook page plugin not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040962/facebook-page-plugin-not-working-properly)

[Facebook like plugin showing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310965/facebook-like-plugin-showing-error)

[Facebook Page Plugin Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137186/facebook-page-plugin-error)

fb docs : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

and many other posts but cant find useful information.

The problem i am facing is when I click the like button, it shows a popup window to confirm the like action having url mentioning an error. image link is attached for clarity
[see this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsWya.png)

by clicking ok it works fine and updates the like count and change caption of like button as liked. When i click the button again it caption reverts back to previous but count does not decreases(i don't know if this is a feature or bug). Then clicking the button third time will change the caption as "error" and disabled it without giving error in browsers console.

i have some other queries

1 . why there is error in url of popup like in image i attached.

2 . the old like button does not open like confirm box, it just add like counter or subtract it by clicking again is it possible to disable the confirm like popup window of page plugin.

3 . why it not update like counter upon clicking the button again to undo like and button caption changes to "error". [see this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNjh6.png)

Comment: The confirmation popup gets triggered when the algorithms detect suspicious activity (such as someone liking/unliking repeatedly during testing ...) it will go away on its own again once enough users have confirmed that they indeed intended to like the page, and this was not a fraudulent attempt at click-jacking or the like.

Comment: thank you @CBroe for your comment I have also read about that fact. I would also like to know about error in url of popup window i attach in image and error on like button as  i mention in point 1 and 3. thank you again for your reply